# How to manage custom fonts in web application (system.drawing)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, fonts, system.drawing, truetype

I have an application that **writes text onto images** using `System.Drawing` (C#).

I am using specific fonts to do this.

Since I can't rely on my shared hosting servers to have all the custom fonts I may need (and since the list of fonts is likely to grow), how can I manage the fonts used for my application?

Could I include **`.ttf`** files in my project and reference them somehow?

What about a SQL database containing fonts?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Load fonts from file on a C# application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/544972/load-fonts-from-file-on-a-c-sharp-application)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It should be possible to store your font files on disk or in database, and then use the [PrivateFontCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.text.privatefontcollection.aspx) class to use the fonts at runtime.

Here is how you would use it:

```
    PrivateFontCollection collection = new PrivateFontCollection();
    // Add the custom font families. 
    // (Alternatively use AddMemoryFont if you have the font in memory, retrieved from a database).
    collection.AddFontFile(@"E:\Downloads\actest.ttf");
    using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(bm))
    {
        // Create a font instance based on one of the font families in the PrivateFontCollection
        Font f = new Font(collection.Families.First(), 16);
        g.DrawString("Hello fonts", f, Brushes.White, 50, 50);
    }
```