# How can I load custom fonts to draw over image on Windows Azure?

Tags: c#, azure, fonts

I need to use custom fonts for drawing on my own application.

Is it possible to install by deployment scripts?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[How to manage custom fonts in web application (system.drawing)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3909520/how-to-manage-custom-fonts-in-web-application-system-drawing)

> It should be possible to store your
>   font files on disk or in database, and
>   then use the
>   [PrivateFontCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.text.privatefontcollection.aspx) class to
>   use the fonts at runtime.
>
> Here is how you would use it:

```
    PrivateFontCollection collection = new PrivateFontCollection();
    // Add the custom font families. 
    // (Alternatively use AddMemoryFont if you have the font in memory, retrieved from a database).
    collection.AddFontFile(@"E:\Downloads\actest.ttf");
    using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(bm))
    {
        // Create a font instance based on one of the font families in the PrivateFontCollection
        Font f = new Font(collection.Families.First(), 16);
        g.DrawString("Hello fonts", f, Brushes.White, 50, 50);
    }
```

Cheers.