# How to include a non-standard font-face in azure hosted website without using visual studio?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Trying to use a custom font in a simple static content website publish via git to azure. The website project isn't wrapped in a Visual studio solution. There is no web.config so how can I get the custom font to work or any static content such as .json files to be accessible?

This solution implies your using visual studio which I am not. [How to include a non-standard font-face in azure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5838251/how-to-include-a-non-standard-font-face-in-azure)

My exact error is:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://fakewebsitename.azurewebsites.net/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.0.3
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you just have to add a MIME type for the font in your `web.config` it will look something like this for your `woff` font

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <staticContent>
            <remove fileExtension=".woff" /> 
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/x-font-woff" />
         </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

IIS by default will prevent download of static files you don't specify MIME types for.

**Edit:** added `<remove fileExtension=".woff" />` based on @TealFawn suggestion

Comment: Excellent that helped almost perfectly. I just copied that into a file called the file web.config, in the root folder. I did have to add one change my final result was:

    <configuration>
   <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <remove fileExtension=".woff" /> <!-- In case IIS already has this mime type -->
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/x-font-woff" />
    </staticContent>    
    </system.webServer>
    </configuration>