# How to use custom fonts on Azure Websites

Tags: azure, fonts, telerik

How to either:

- Install a custom font onto the Azure Websites instance (if it doesn't exist).
- Inject the PrivateFontCollection into the active PrintDocument settings to override fonts utilized.

Situational Specifics:

The goal is to render the custom font OCR-A-Extended using Telerik reporting.  Telerik's default statement is that the fonts must be installed on the system because that's what MS requires.  Pre-generation, access to PrivateFontCollection does not appear available.  The final assumption is that installation of a custom font is required.

Notes:

- Direct access like "[How can I install custom fonts on Windows Azure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5114658/how-can-i-install-custom-fonts-on-windows-azure)" are not available as the GDI+ is being accessed via 3rd party dll.
- Usage is a background process and not subject to CSS font loading since nothing is provided to the user, thus no dependencies on the user's system fonts.

Comment: Is this being presented in real-time to users? Could the generation be snapped of an placed on a Worker Role or VM? If so you could deploy the fonts as part of that cloud service using a startup script.

Comment: Simon: It's being generated in real-time in the background. It's not being presented to the users.  I've heard that cloud role can possibly install a font through several work arounds.  However, for the time being I'm focusing on azure websites.  If it proves there are no other means possible, I'll add a VM and isolate the pdf generation to that vm (as a last resort).  Any other clarifications, just let me know. Thx!

Comment: Simon: do you know if the same "startup script" process, used for worker roles, can be run on azure websites to install fonts?

Comment: I have the same problem, I want to generate pdf from html file in my website, but the font does not bind. it's a GDI issue. and i have nothing to do with i, unfortunately.