# Font Problem in .NET 4

Tags: c#, font-face

i am developing a simple application on .NET 4 visual studio 2010. i am using default font
microsoft san serif. but i am was writing in bangla (unicode) for label button text. but my development pc show everyting correctly. but when i install this program on other computer then font not showing correct format only some rectangle showing.

in client pc i also install bangla writing softare also.

Thanks
Tonmoy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're writing a WinForms application you can load the font into a private collection. Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/544972/load-fonts-from-file-on-a-c-application/545044#545044). If you do that then the font will always be available to your app.

> There's a class
>   System.Drawing.Text.PrivateFontCollection
>   in System.Drawing.dll which can manage
>   fonts on a per application basis.
>
> All you do is that you maintain this
>   collection within your app and you add
>   fonts through AddFontFile or
>   AddMemoryFont and you'll then be able
>   to use that font as if it was
>   installed on your system.
>
> It's like installing the font for the
>   application only. The font will be
>   uninstalled once the process
>   terminates.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds simply like the target computer doesn't have the necessary fonts. Perhaps they have a different version or locale of windows (with a different "Sans Serif" font), or maybe you are actually using a different font that the target PC lacks.