# Embed a font in the binary with Free Pascal/Lazarus under Linux

Tags: linux, fonts, lazarus, freepascal

In the hopes that this question will not be marked as duplicate since all of these only have Windows solutions:

- [How can I temporarily load a font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107611/how-can-i-temporarily-load-a-font)
- [Embedding a font in Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2984474/embedding-a-font-in-delphi)
- [How to use external fonts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305344/how-to-use-external-fonts)

My question is this: How can one do the same without using [AddFontMemResourceEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183325%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), since it's Windows only, under a Linux OS?

*On a side note, for the OSX crowd, this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444717/embed-font-in-a-mac-bundle) might help.*